# I need help with this limit: $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k\log k}$ No idea how to approach it.

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{2\log2}+\frac{1}{3\log3}+...+\frac{1}{n\log n}$$

(log stands for natural logarithm). I don't have the slightest idea about how to calculate this limit.

Comment: Hint: Integral test or Cauchy condensation.

Comment: @zhw. i haven't been taught these things yet. i will look them up. thank you

Comment: the same idea used to prove that the harmonic serie diverges works here

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\dfrac{1}{x\ln x}$ is a decreasing function
\begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{k\ln k} & > \frac{1}{(k+1) \ln(k+1)} \\
  \frac{1}{k\ln k} & > \int_{k}^{k+1} \frac{dx}{x\ln x} \\
  \sum_{k=2}^{n} \frac{1}{k\ln k} & > \int_{2}^{n+1} \frac{dx}{x\ln x} \\
  &= \ln \ln (n+1)-\ln \ln 2
\end{align*}

which tends to infinity so the sum diverges.

Answer (score 0):

By [Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) the series
$$ \sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{n\log n} $$
is convergent iff the series
$$ \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{2^m}{2^m \log(2^m)} = \frac{1}{\log 2}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{1}{m} $$
is convergent, but the last series is the harmonic series, which is divergent (by Cauchy's condensation test again, if you like).